# Second Order Coherence of NOON State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

Given the entangled state $\vert NOON \rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert N,0\rangle + \vert 0,N\rangle)$ how can the second order coherence function at time $\tau$ and 0 be calculated?

I know that $g^{(2)}(\tau)$ can be defined for a quantum state as $g^{(2)}(\tau) = \frac{\langle \hat a(0)^\dagger \hat a(\tau)^\dagger \hat a(\tau) \hat a(0) \rangle}{\langle \hat a(0)^\dagger\hat a(0) \rangle}$. However I'm not too sure how I can apply this to the NOON state since it's entangled and, as I understand it, the annihilation operator and creation operator are different for the two different states.

Attempting:
$\langle \hat a(0)^\dagger \hat a(\tau)^\dagger \hat a(\tau) \hat a(0) \rangle = \langle NOON \vert \hat a(0)^\dagger \hat a(\tau)^\dagger \hat a(\tau) \hat a(0) \vert NOON \rangle$

$\langle \hat a(0)^\dagger \hat a(\tau)^\dagger \hat a(\tau) \hat a(0) \rangle = (\langle NOON \vert \hat a(0)^\dagger \hat a(\tau)^\dagger) (\hat a(\tau) \hat a(0) \vert NOON \rangle) $

$(\hat a(\tau) \hat a(0) \vert NOON \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a(\tau)(\hat a(0)\vert N,0\rangle + \hat a(0)\vert 0,N\rangle)$

However I'm not sure now how to apply the operator to these quantum states, since the creation operator for each of the states is different. How do I go about this?

Comment: Does no one have any advice?

Comment: Your NOON state consists of two independent modes, but your g2 function is defined only for a single mode. That's why it seems strange. You need to use the multimode version of coherence function.